# SQL Server 2017 -Database Restore, Overwrite without REPLACE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, database-restore

Is this just me, or is it a wider issue. -- Turns out it is just me.

In SQL Server 2017 with CU15 (14.0.3162.1) you can restore a database over an existing database **without** the REPLACE option being used. The 'Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)' option is now irreverent and is ignored.

Confirmed with SSMS 17.8.1 & 17.9.1, both via the GUI and New Query window.

The backups being restored were from SQL Server 2014 (12.0.6024.0) and local backups (SQL Server 2017) exhibit the same behaviour.

So

```sql
RESTORE DATABASE [TMP1] FROM  DISK = N'F:\tmp\TMP1.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
```

Is the same as

```sql
RESTORE DATABASE [TMP1] FROM  DISK = N'F:\tmp\TMP1.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The REPLACE option overrides several important safety checks that
>   restore normally performs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

When doing a `RESTORE`, SQL Server checks for certain conditions that may lead to problems.  As long as none of those conditions are applicable, it will perform the backup, even if that means overwriting an existing database.  If any of the safety checks fail, it will give an error message.   By adding the REPLACE option, you are telling SQL Server that it's okay to overwrite the files regardless of the safety checks.

------------ EDIT: ---------------

How does SQL Server determine whether the database being restored is the same as the database being overwritten?  I did not know the answer when I started writing this, so I've done some research.  For this purpose SQL Server uses the `FamilyGUID`.  Every time you create a new database it is *tattooed* with a `FamilyGUID`.  When a database is backed up, the `FamilyGUID` is carried along. When it comes time to restore, SQL Server compares the `FamilyGUID` of the backup to the database being overwritten.  If they are the same, then there is no problem.  If they are different, you need to use `REPLACE`.

Perhaps in your case, the `FamilyGUID`s are the same.

To find the `FamilyGUID` of the backup, use:

```
RESTORE headeronly FROM DISK = N'Q:\MyBackup.bak'
```

To find the `FamilyGUID` of the database being overwritten, you can use:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) as DatabaseName, database_guid, family_guid
FROM master.sys.database_recovery_status
```

Are they the same?

Comment: The problem is that without REPLACE present the databases are still being overwritten.


Restore normally prevents accidentally overwriting a database with a different database.

Comment: But it doesn't, and never has, prevented replacing an existing database with an earlier version of the same database, so long as there are no transactions in the transaction log that haven't either been backed-up (FULL recovery), or truncated on checkpoint (SIMPLE recovery).

Comment: The FamilyGUID must have been the same, it wasn't behaviour I was expecting. Good the learn something that I thought I already understood.